# JQuery alert doesnot work on onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get an alert after three characters. What's wrong with my code.

Html

```
<input type="text" id="name"/>
```

javascript

```
$('#name').onkeyup(function(){
    var info = $('#name').val();
    if(info.length >3){alert('thank you');}
});
```

Comment: why not `$('#name').on('keyup', function(){` ?

Comment: Did you get any error in console?

Comment: 'onkeyup' is js event listener. You should use 'keyup'.

Answer (score 2):

Use keyup event, there is no onkeyup event

```
$('#name').keyup(function(){
    var info = $('#name').val();
    if(info.length >3){alert('thank you');}
});
```